# Make bootstrap columns fill screen width in grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=grid-layout-for-all-devices) is a link to some bootstrap code

In the demo you can see the cells resize and stack nicely (use full screen for best effect).

However, the cells don't fill up the entire screen width!!

How do I have an identical setup, only the cells always cover the entirety of the screen horizontally??

Comment: There are so many questions of similar type. Please use google or search box of stackoverflow, before posting such common question.

Comment: Or read through the Bootstrap documentation.. There's load of answers to alot of questions on here, on there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace main wrapper class from `container` to `container-fluid` and it will fill to `width:100%`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the **container** div tag or add `container-fluid` instead of `container`

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 1</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 2</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 4</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 5</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 6</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 7</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 8</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 9</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 10</p></div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 11</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 12</p></div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why to remove container div tag?

Comment: @SanjeevK try it, still works. however it has no left or right borders/padding

Comment: row is designed be in container, else you'll have problem with the negative margins